# How to enable spell vchecker in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, spell-check

I have added the Spell Checker 1.2 add on but my messages in my email browser are not checked for spelling, or if they are, the mistakes are not highlighted or identified in any way.

How can I enable this simple tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I needed to load in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A spell-checker certainly comes already on in v3+, and I'm pretty sure it was there in v2. What version of FF are you running?

Should show up in Tools > Add-Ins, btw.

Comment: Thanks. IF you go to
http://cid-b8e445b7518940f1.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Documents/Firefox%20Spell%20Check.png

you will see a screen shot of my addons. I added the spellchecker you see there butnothing seems to work.

Comment: Hi.

I did more research and found that I needed to add a dictionary. I did this and now all works.

Thanks for your help.
Don